# How to click on link where there is image in front in python using webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, helper

I am trying to click on the link behind the image on eBay.

**Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
url='https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Pet+Sim+X+1B+25B+100B+250B+Gems%2Fdiamonds+Pet+Simulator+X+Cheep%2BInstant+Delivery&_sacat=0&_fcid=1'
driver = webdriver.Chrome("E:\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.minimize_window()
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(url)
#Gets all the elements of images on page
titles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//img[@class="s-item__image-img"]')
time.sleep(2)
#gets the element of first image
element=titles[0]
#clicks
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).click().perform()
time.sleep(10)
driver.close()
```

So what it does is collects all elements of the image in a list and then I can click any specific element/IMG by just giving list index

[URL](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=Pet%20Sim%20X%201B%2025B%20100B%20250B%20Gems%2Fdiamonds%20Pet%20Simulator%20X%20Cheep%2BInstant%20Delivery&_sacat=0&_fcid=1)

I can't click the image it should open a new tab but it doesn't
please help me.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPath locator you are using here is not good enough.
Instead of

```py
titles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//img[@class="s-item__image-img"]')
```

Please use

```py
titles=driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@id="srp-river-results"]//img[@class="s-item__image-img"]')
```

This will give you correct results.
You should also remove the redundant `driver.maximize_window()` and use Expected Conditions explicit waits instead of hardcoded pauses like `time.sleep(2)`

Comment: hi Thanks  for your time buddy but it still does not clicks on the image